# Image is behind of background

Tags: android

I want output like below image.

[image]

I have background image like

[image]

Now I want to put image back part . camera part image should be above of user. I try below code but not working

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/user"
            android:background="@drawable/changephoto"
             />
```

I also try framelayout but not working.

Comment: FrameLayout or Relative layout should to solve this problem for you. Use different imageviews for camera part and user part

Answer (score 0):

You should use User image as `ImageView Background image` and Camera image as `ImageView Resource Image`

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/changephoto"
            android:background="@drawable/user" />
```

Comment: Please make sure your camera image is transparent and is in .png format.

Answer (score 0):

### create below image transparent:

[image]

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:onClick="setimag"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

where back is **your image** and **ic_launcher** as you k'no

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case 100:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                // imgv.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                        yourSelectedImage);
                imgv.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** do what you want to do in this way.

The *solution* is to have **three separated images**, one for the white background, one for the camera image, last one for the actual profile image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="your background image" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="profile image" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="camera photo"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Change Photo"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```